# How to dispose HttpClient after it's finished?

Tags: c#, async-await, httpclient, razor-pages, using

I want to use `HttpClient` to get content for my web page.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
{
    NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(Settings.Username, Settings.Password);

    using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials })
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        Content = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(requestUriString);
    }

    return Page();
}
```

The problem is that my `using` statements cause the `HttpClient` and `HttpClientHandler` objects to be destroyed before `GetStringAsync()` has completed.

I can remove the `using` statements, but then I can't be assured the connections get disposed in a timely fashion.

Note that `HttpClient` does not implement `IAsyncDisposable` and so using `await using` is not an option.

How can I ensure my HTTP objects get disposed of as soon as possible without disposing them before the code is finished?

Comment: The code in your question won't even compile. Your method is not marked as async. Please make sure you create a real [MCVE]. And of course, you *shouldn't* dispose HttpClient, see [You're Using HttpClient Wrong And It's Destabilizing Your Software](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). One easy fix is to use a library that takes care of some of those details for you, such as [Flurl](https://flurl.dev/).

Comment: @mason: Thanks I've fixed the issue. However, I'm not so much looking for help debugging my code as much as I'm trying to understand how this case should be handled.

Comment: In this example, `Dispose` must be called after `GetStringAsync` ends. Is it possible that you used an utility method instead with `using` that just returns a task instead of awaiting it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So HttpClient is actually a bit weird in the context of being an IDisposable. Even though it implements the IDisposable interface, [Microsoft actually advises against placing it in a using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0#remarks).

If you are using it in an ASP.NET Core context, you should use the [HttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) to manage the lifetime of your HttpClients. If not, it is recommended to use a single static instance, but be wary that this can cause other issues, such as DNS staleness.

Comment: Interesting. Looking into this further. And I'm using .NET 5.

Comment: Oh, I actually forgot that one came out. HttpClientFactory is also a thing in ASP.NET on .NET 5.

Comment: The HttpClient factory, actually, manages the lifetime of the HttpClient's HttpMessageHandler. HttpClients returned by the factory can safely be disposed.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article helpful when I had a similar issue: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/
Here's an excerpt of the code you're looking for:

```
private static HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
public static async Task Main(string[] args) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting connections");
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        var result = await Client.GetAsync("http://aspnetmonsters.com");
        Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Connections done");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: You've linked to helpful info, but you need to actually explain why this code is recommended *in your answer*. Links can die over time, but we want our answers to still be useful.